# Dart: handling an exception from another package

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to handle an exception from a package that I am importing (not one that I have written).

The code in the 3rd party package, for example is

```
Future<Map<String, double>> getLocation() => _channel
  .invokeMethod('getLocation')
  .then((result) => result.cast<String, double>())
```

If I wrap a call in my own project/code to `getLocation()` in a try/catch, it doesn't work, as my understanding is because it's async it will get dumped via catchError.

Indeed, if I edit the 3rd party file, and add

```
  .catchError(( e ) { print( 'In getLocation package error' + e.toString() );});
```

this catches the exception

However, that code is not a package that I've written, I'm hesitant to edit that file. Naturally I can suggest a change request, but is there any other method of getting around these async errors when it's internal to other packages you don't maintain ?

I have already tried

```
try { 
  var test = location.getLocation(); 
} catch(e) {
  print (e.toString());
}
```

But this doesn't capture it, only the catchError in the 3rd part code which I've hacked does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `async`/`await` with `try`/`catch`

```
Future<Map<String, double>> getLocation() async { 
  try {
    var test = await location.getLocation(); 
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());        
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but this would still mean editing the other packages files which I'm not the author of, which I'm trying to avoid ?

Comment: You can do this as well where you call `getLocation()` and wrap it with `try`/`catch`. I don't understand from your question what code is in your project and what is in the 3rd-party package.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question to be a bit more clear as to which code is from the 3rd party.